# Should the list of users in Sitecore User Manager be empty, when using Sitecore Client Account Managing role?

Tags: sitecore-client

I need a role that only allows creation/edition/delete of the users, roles and domains in Sitecore 8.1. I've done some research and the sitecore\Sitecore Client Account Managing role fits.

Regarding some Sitecore documentation, sitecore\Sitecore Client Account Managing role "gives the user access to maintain users, roles, and domains in the Access Manager, the Domain Manager, the Role Manager, and the User Manager".

I've created an user, member of Account Managing role, and the user has access  to Access Manager, Domain Manager, Role Manager, and User Manager. However, the list of users in User Manager is empty. The user is able to create a new user and add some roles to it, however it is not able to see the list of the existing/new users.

In order to see the list of existing/new users I need to login as admin.

Please let me know if anyone faced similar issue.

Comment: Did you check view permission?

Comment: @BalajiKuppuswamy
 I've switched to the Core DB and selected my new role that inherits from the sitecore\Sitecore Client Account Managing role in the Security Editor tool. 
Then I went to /sitecore/system/Settings/Security/User Manager and I changed the access rights on the new role (read/write/rename/create/delete access)...but the list of users remains empty for the user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this on a clean version of Sitecore 8.1.1, 8.1.3, and 8.2.3 and - as confirmed by @maz - a user with the Sitecore Client Account Managing role should have access to view the list of items.

There are a couple of things that I would do to try to validate and correct the issue:

1. Install a clean `core` database and point your connection strings at it. Log in as an admin and create some test users, including one, testmanager (name is arbitrary), that has only the `sitecore\Sitecore Client Account Managing` role. Log out of the admin account and log back in with the "testmanager" account. Verify that you can see the list of users. If this works, then you know that the issue is in your `core` database only, and can be solved by replacing it. If not, then you may have another corruption in your Sitecore instance. At this point, I would continue to Step 2.
2. Only try this after you have tried Step 1. Go into your App_Config folder and replace your configs, excluding your ConnectionStrings and DataFolder settings, with clean ones. Specifically, make sure that you have replaced those in the App_Config\Security folder. If that doesn't work, replace the remainder of the configs, still excluding ConnectionStrings and DataFolder settings, and retest. If you are still unable to see the list of users at this point, there is a more serious issue with your Sitecore instance. I recommend that you file a Sitecore Support Ticket and send then a full Sitecore Support Package, using SSPG.
3. Reconnect your original `core` database and add all of the custom and default security roles available to a new "testmanager" account. Log in as the "testmanager" user and verify that you can see the list of all users. Either one-by-one (brute-force-search) or in groups (binary-search), remove roles from the "testmanager" user until the list of displayed roles is no longer displayed. If troubleshooting via binary-search, re-add the last set of removed roles and proceed with brute-force-search until you find the role that is required to see the list. Note that this investigation step seeks to find a role that grants the ability to see the list of users in the User Manager. If there is not, then you know that replacing your `core` database is your only viable option.

Answer (score 0):

By default, your user should be able to see all users. However, the likeliest explanation is that this access has been restricted to specific domains on which no users exist.

While logged in as admin, check the "Member of" tab of your user, and click the "Domains" button. Make sure to either add or remove all domains if you want the user to manage users for all domains.

[image]

Comment: I've added all the Domains and logged in and then I've removed all of them as you recommended and logged in. 
While logged in as "user member of  sitecore\Sitecore Client Account Managing role "I am not able to see the list of users, it still remains empty. I am only able to see the list as admin...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Open Domain Manager and check that if your user's domain is locally managed. If that's the case, then you'll need to explicitly add all domains that she/he is allowed manage, otherwise the default will be "user's own domain only".

Comment: my user's domain is not locally managed. 
I think my company has introduced a bug, because now, there are more roles with the same issue...Thank you so much anyway!